# Java: parsing file path

Tags: java, substring, indexof

I need to parse a file path to get the filename from it. What confuses me is that windows uses `\` as the delimeter and linux - `/` and somehow the provided filepath can even contain both delimeters at the same time.

Of course I can do:

```
int slash = filePath.lastIndexOf("/");
int backslash = filePath.lastIndexOf("\\");
fileName = filePath.substring(slash > backslash ? slash : backslash);
```

but is there a better way in case I have more delimiters? (probably not for a file path)

Comment: `File f = new File(fileName); String name = f.getName();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the `File` class:

```
String fileName = new File(path).getName();
```

It handles forward and backwards slashes, plus combinations of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String separator =System.getProperty("path.separator");
```

to get you systems separator.

Comment: This won't do as there may be both separators at the same time.